# Compilation error complaining about value not being a function

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, linqpad

I am trying to experiment in F# for one of the utility tools we need, wherein we want to trawl through a folder of xml files and look for a particular tag. If found then insert another similar tag alongwith it. Finally, output all the filenames for which such additional tags have been inserted. But am getting a compilation error, of which I am not able to make a lot of sense.

```
let configFile = 
    Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine("rootdir", "relativepath"), @"*.xml")    
    |> Seq.map(fun configFileName -> 
                let xmlNavigator = XPathDocument(configFileName).CreateNavigator()
                let node = xmlNavigator.SelectSingleNode(@"Product/ABc[@type='xyz']")
                match node with
                | null -> "not configuration present"
                | _ -> 
                    let nodeAppender() = node.InsertAfter("<Risk type=""abc1"" methodology=""xyz1""/>")
                    let parentNode = node.SelectAncestors(XPathNodeType.Root, false)
                    parentNode.Current.OuterXml)        
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

The compilation error is as below:

```
This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

Comment: Do you use `nodeAppender` anywhere? `node.InsertAfter` will not have any effect until you call `nodeAppender` function.

Comment: Thats a very good point!! I removed the "let nodeAppender() = ", but doesnt seem to like it.

Comment: You can use `|> ignore` or `let _ =` to declare an unused value. The point is you should declare a value, not a function.

Comment: @pad : using the second option gives me the < Specified method is not supported. > exception at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is escaped improperly. It should be:

```
node.InsertAfter("<Risk type=\"abc1\" methodology=\"xyz1\"/>")
```

EDIT: Apparently I was typing this as Brian posted his answer. Either escaping each quote char or prefixing with `@` as-is will work.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! That was the problem. I had picked it up from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In that example the string is prefixed with `@`. However, I like the new triple-quoted strings for XML.

Comment: Agree! But not sure if the triple quotes work in LinqPad. Coz my first attempt was with the triple quotes.

Comment: Probably not. I doubt LinqPad has been updated to work with F# 3.0.

Comment: The recent LINQPad betas work with F# 3 (obviously you'll need to install the latter)

Comment: @JoeAlbahari : Thanks! Will do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would help to point out what line/column the error location is at.

At a glance, in nodeAppender, it looks like you left off the `@` on the string literal, which means it is five strings in a row (rather than one string with escaped quotes), which may be the cause of the error.